# Pass response data of one Http request to another Http request in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am building a logic apps where I need to pass response data of one Http request to another Http request in Azure Logic Apps.

The first Http request is POST method and is returning this data.

```
{
  "ID": "892069751085535232",
  "Name": "Test",  
  "source": "retailcloud",
  "metadata": {
    "OrderID": "894",
    "DeviceID": "123"
  }
}
```

The next will be again POST request with something like this data.

```
{
  id: response.id,
  order_id: response.metadata.OrderId
}
```

How I can pass here Id and OrderId? Like which Logic app inbuild functions i need to use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your first HTTP action is called **HTTP1** and the second HTTP action is called **HTTP2**.

You have 2 options.

1. add a [Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) action between them, use the output of **HTTP1** as a content, and use sample payload to generate schema. Then you can use dynamic content from this action in **HTTP2**:

   `{ "id": <ID from Parse JSON>, "order_id": <OrderID from Parse JSON> }`
2. do not add 'Parse JSON' - and use an Expression instead of the Dynamic content in the body of **HTTP2**:

   `{ "id": <body('HTTP1')?['ID']>, "order_id": <body('HTTP1')?['metadata']?['OrderID']> }`

Ignore the angle brackets in the examples above - replace them with the actual dynamic content or with the expression as needed.

Comment: Yes, I used the 2nd approach and is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using 2 Connectors one is `When HTTP request is received`and the other is`HTTP` Connectors.

In order to make your properties available for next Connector I am just adding the sample pay load.
[image]

Then paste your sample payload to the area and click done. You ll have a generated schema for your payload

[image]

Then add the `Http` Connector and add the method and url. For the ID and OrderID properties to get passed you need to add the properties to the body which are automatically generated when you click `Dynamic Contents`.

[image]